# how to disable warning message with sidekiq in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq

I'm fairly new to rails and testing.  Documentation says to add this code to spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec::Sidekiq.configure do |config|
  config.warn_when_jobs_not_processed_by_sidekiq = false
end
```

but when I do, i get an error:

```
uninitialized constant RSpec::Sidekiq (NameError)
```

Comment: Confirm that you have `gem 'rspec-sidekiq'` in your Gemfile and that you have run `bundle install`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have rspec 3, then you should try to add following code to `rails_helper.rb` instead of `spec_helper.rb`